# To get default values in one2many odoo 12

Tags: odoo

actually i got 2 models,A and B ,connection same as sale.order and sale.order.line ,that connecting line here is medicine_line it is a one2many field.so when adding a specialist_name in model A,"each line" in the model B's(Notebook) specialist_name wants to get by default .

I have tried below code but getting the name only on the first line of the notebook:

***.py**

medicine_line = One2many field

```
@api.onchange('specialist_name')
def _onchange_specialist_name(self):
    for record in self:
        for each in record.medicine_line:
            if record.specialist_name:
                lines = [(5, 0, 0)]
                for line in self.specialist_name:
                    val = {
                        'specialist_name': line.id,
                    }
                    lines.append((0, 0, val))
                record.each = lines
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the default value in the context.

```xml
<group>
    <field name="specialist_name"/>
</group>

<field name="medicine_line" context="{'default_specialist_name': specialist_name}">
    <tree editable="bottom">
        ...
        <field name="specialist_name"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Each time you click the `Add item` link button the specialist name should be filled with the default value specified in the context.

Comment: Thankyou so much,im a beginner thats why i keep asking and building by logics and language.its been such a favour,thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, Feel free to check the accept flag.